# Why did Hanumana want to eat the sun?

Tags: hanuman, surya

I want to know why Hanumana wanted to the eat sun ? 
I've heard one story from our Gujrati loksahitya kalakar(Artist) by the name Ishardan Gadhvi in his program that Hanumana's mother got curse that her son would die before sun set on the day he was born. Hanumana wanted to eat sun as he didn't want the sun to set.

Is that true ? Or is there any other reason for Hanumana wanting to eat the sun.

Comment: I think he just thought it was a fruit.

Comment: ok... there is  no another reason ?

Comment: this leads me to another question, Why Rahu want to eat sun every time. :(

Comment: @Friendy It's to take revenge on Surya and Chandra; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/491/36

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As it is said that lord Hanuman was very mischievous during his childhood. One day he saw Sun through the leaves of a tree and thought of it as a fruit, so he flew in order to eat it. 
>   It has nothing to do with any curse. Rather, he was hit by Indra's vajra when he refused to release Surya and later on was given many boons by different Gods.

Source: Hanuman Chalisa by Goswami Tulsidas .

> जुग सहस्र जोजन पर भानू।
>   लील्यो ताहि मधुर फल जानू॥ १८ ॥
>
> The Sun is at thousand *yojanas* (a unit of measurement of distance), and thought of it as a sweet fruit.

Source :Sankatmochan Hanumaashtak

> बाल समय रवि भक्षी लियो तब,
>   तीनहुं लोक भयो अंधियारों ।
>  ताहि सों त्रास भयो जग को,
>   यह संकट काहु सों जात  न टारो । 
>  
>   देवन आनि करी बिनती तब,
>   छाड़ी दियो रवि कष्ट निवारो I
>
> During your childhood, you engulfed the Sun and it caused darkness in three worlds (Swarg, Prithvi, Pataal)
>   The worlds were in havoc, this panic was not controlled by anyone.
>   Gods came to you and prayed(requested), then you let Sun go free and eased the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Ok sure...

Comment: You shouldn't just say the Hanuman Chalisa, you should give specific citations and/or quotes from it.

Comment: Ok will update with exact lines...

Comment: One more thing: this is an English language site, so you should provide a translation for anything you quote from another language.  Sorry for bombarding you with rules!

Comment: @ABcDexter Hanuman Chalisa and Sankatmochan Hanumaashtak. this I know, I posted   this question because I heard somewhere this  curse story

Comment: @BhavinPatel I haven't any story other than this but I'm always open for different interpretations of our texts :-D

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It's fine. I have used other SE sites, just found this one... And yes, will update with the translations :-)