# Did our ancestors calculate the distance between Prithvi (Earth) and Surya (Sun) correctly?

Tags: belief, hanuman, surya, earth

In Hanuman Chalisa, it is said:

> जुग सहस्र जोजन पर भानू। लील्यो ताहि मधुर फल जानू॥ १८ ॥

meaning:

> The Sun is at thousand yojanas(a unit of measurement of distance), [and thought of it as a sweet fruit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/why-did-hanumana-want-to-eat-the-sun?).

As per calculations,

```
1 Yug      = 12000 years  
1 Sahastra = 1000  
1 Yojan    = 8 Miles  

Yug x Sahastra x Yojan = par Bhanu  
12000 x 1000 x 8 miles = 96000000 miles

1 mile = 1.6kms  

96000000 miles = 96000000 x 1.6kms = 1536000000 kms to Sun
```

[NASA has said](http://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/k-4/features/F_Measuring_the_Distance_Student_Pages.html) that, the above is the exact distance between Earth and Sun([during](http://www.universetoday.com/15462/how-far-are-the-planets-from-the-sun/) [the Aphelion](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphelion)).

Does this prove that our ancestors calculated the  distance between Earth and Sun centuries before scientists did it?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE Here is Similar Question with answer from Quora https://www.quora.com/Is-the-following-post-true

Comment: Debunked: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32499/was-suns-distance-mentioned-correctly-in-hanuman-chalisa-the-16-th-century-p

Comment: If you want evidence based confirmation it's best to post on Skeptics.so along with here. People here are experienced with scriptures, but they always misquote science.

Comment: @Wally That is not debunking but BS, viewpoint of a so called skeptic who thinks he's speaking science but know neither Science nor Sanskrit!

Comment: @ABcDexter The skeptic presents mutiple views and presents all the numbers and language mis-interpretations. These people are picking one out of a million numbers that too years and time and language misinterpreted.

Comment: Look, being skeptical never means that you defy history, and it's because of the philosophy of religion that we(as in human beings) have had, which makes us logical enough to question. So, it's not good to not have an open mind, also being Scientific in approach doesn't imply that you or anyone start attacking any religion!

Comment: I agree on what calculation was stated here. But i think that time if something is too far they assume and say its 1000s of yojan(miles) away from here. So can we consider this as well over here? No offence to the calculation shown here.

Comment: No. How did they convert yojana and yuga to modern metric system. There is no where in Hindu scripture where it says a Yojana is 8 miles. It's pure algebra by modern Hindu preachers

Comment: If you're interested, you may check out my answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58656/24460 Thanks @ABcDexter

Comment: @TheHungryDictator The calculation is quite wrong here actually, if you want you may check out my answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58656/24460. Thanks

Comment: @Notty There's nothing to debunk here actually. It's just that this caupāī is commonly misinterpreted, and the confusion is cleared up in my answer. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58656/24460 Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Interesting Facts & Fascinating Story of Hanuman Chalisa!**

Hanuman Chalisa has *40 Chaupais* (*Chalis*=40 in *Hindi*) on Hanuman is a devotional hymn dedicated to Bajrang Bali by the Great Indian poet, philosopher and saint Shri Goswami Tulsidas. Born in the 16th century, Tulsidas authored [Hanuman Chalisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman_Chalisa) in Awadhi language when he was quite young.

**Hanuman Chalisa Tells Us The Distance Between Earth & Sun**

When Hanuman was very young, [he flew from Earth to the sky in the direction of the Sun to eat it, assuming it to be a ripe, luscious fruit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/why-did-hanumana-want-to-eat-the-sun/8022#8022). Tulsidas while stating this incident in the *chalisa* in simple languages gives the distance between Earth and the Sun.

The Line is –

> **“जुग सहस्र जोजन पर भानू।
>   लील्यो ताहि मधुर फल जानू॥ १८ ॥”**

Meaning:

> Sun is at the distance of *sahastra*(thousand) *yojan*(an anstonomical unit of distance).

After certain intellectuals decoded this famous line of Hanuman Chalisa by Tulsidas they could find the distance of Earth, they found that tt is exactly the same as that discovered by scientist later.

In the year 1653, astronomer Christian Huygens with his guesswork estimated the distance from earth to the sun.

Now let’s see what the intellectuals (Garjajev’s Research Group) got after decoding the lines:

**1 Yuga is 12000 years

1 Sahastra is 1000.

1 Yojan is 8 miles**

Thus,

*Yuga Shastra Yojan par Bhanu*  means

**12000 X 1000 X 8 = 96000000 miles

and 1 mile is 1.6 km

So, 96000000 X 1.6 = 1536000000 km**

This is the exact round figure distance of earth from Sun on 3rd July because studies mention the distance of 152,093,481 km from earth to sun during the aphelion (The period when earth is farthest from the Sun).
[This is very close to the current figure by NASA.](http://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/k-4/features/F_Measuring_the_Distance_Student_Pages.html)

Comment: How year * miles = miles ? What is per Bhanu? FYI, i'm not against Tulsidas or Hanuman but want to know the exact truth. But fact is Ancient India was more  advanced than entire world due to words of infallible Vedas.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. Please try to provide links for your research :)

Comment: @TheDestroyer, 'par bhanu पर भानु' could be translated as 'sun is at'. Even though the dimensionality problem remains.

Comment: In my opinion unless Tulsidasa explicitly stated what a Yojana was due to its varying equivelence it cannot be determined.

Comment: Perhaps, you can check out my answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58656/24460  @TheDestroyer  Thanks

Comment: @Haridasa If you are interested, you may check it too.

Comment: @VineetMenon You don't need to worry about dimensionality , if you interpret the caupāī correctly, as pointed in my answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58656/24460 here Thanks

Comment: @Bingming okay!

Answer (score 2):

> juga sahasra jojana para bhānū / 
> līlyo tāhi madhura phala jānū // 
> ~ Tulasīdāsa's Hanumān cālisā ([caupāī 18](https://archive.org/details/xqZf_shri-hanuman-chalisha-gita-press/page/n7/mode/2up))

This famous caupāī is often misinterpreted by many, where they take it as referring to an exact numerical distance b/w Sūrya & Pṛthvi. In actuality, this caupāī is not mentioning this info.

Firstly, *juga* is not used here in the sense of yuga, but in the sense of couple, pair or many. This 'yuga' (*not time duration*) is a synonym of yugma & yugala, as stated in Amarakośaḥ ([2.5.38](https://archive.org/details/AmaraKoshaSatyadevaMisra/page/n171/mode/2up?view=theater)) -

> yugmaṁ tu yugalaṁ yugaṁ

There's another term *yuga* which is a unit of time, and used for specific time durations. In śāstras, it's used to mean three specific durations - 5 yrs, Kṛta/Tretā/Dvāpara/Kali, and mahāyuga (caturyuga + sandhyāṁśas). For more info on the 5 yr duration, check [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58462/24460).
But as stated above, caupāī 18 (of Hanumān cālīsā) is not using the *yuga* that stands for time duration, but another yuga, whose meaning has been explained above through Amarakośa.

Secondly, *sahasra* doesn't necessarily mean 1000. Sahasra is used on several occassions in Veda too (for e.g. sahasrapāda, sahasrākṣa, etc.), but it's used in the sense of ananta, infinite or uncountable or just *very big*. There's a relevant śloka, which I quote below-

> śatādhikāḥ samāḥ saṅkhyā geyāścānantya-vācikāḥ

*[Words for] all numbers higher than hundred are also said to have the meaning 'uncountably many', in certain contexts.*

Therefore, the meaning of *juga sahasra jojana* (in caupāī 18 of Hanumān cālīsā) is thousands and thousands of yojanas or many thousand yojanas or infinitely/uncountably many yojanas.

The distance from sun to earth, is mentioned in siddhāntic jyotiṣa śāstras, and easily calculable.

> śaśirāśayaṣ ṭha cakraṃ te aṃśakalāyojanāni yavañaguṇāḥ / 
> prāṇenaiti kalāṁ bhaṁ khayugāṁśe grahajavo bhavāṁśe ’rkaḥ // 
> ~ Āryabhaṭīya ([1.6](https://archive.org/details/Aryabhatiya1976/Aryabhatiya%20v1%201976/page/n85/mode/2up?view=theater))

*A circle multiplied by 12 is the moon’s signs. These multiplied by 30, 60, 10 are [respectively,] degrees, minutes, and yojanas. The earth moves one minute in one prāṇa. The circumference of the sky [in yojanas] divided by the rotations of a planet in a yuga is the [orbit of the] planet’s motion. The [orbit of the] sun is a sixtieth part of the circumference of the nakṣatra.*

> śaṣṭyā sūryābdānāṁ prapūrayanti grahā bhapariṇāham / 
> divyena nabhaḥparidhiṁ samaṁ bhramantas svakakṣyāsu // 
> ~ Āryabhaṭīya ([3.12](https://archive.org/details/Aryabhatiya1976/Aryabhatiya%20v1%201976/page/n173/mode/2up?view=theater))

*By sixty solar years planets fulfill the circumference of the nakṣatra. Revolving equally in their own orbits, they [fulfill] the circumference of the sky by one divya [year].*

The circumference of moon's orbit (*C<sub>m</sub>*) is 12 X 30 X 60 X 10 = 216000 yojanas. The moon's sidereal rotations in a yuga (*R<sub>m</sub>*) are 57753336 (as per [Āryabhaṭīya 1.3-4](https://archive.org/details/Aryabhatiya1976/Aryabhatiya%20v1%201976/page/n79/mode/2up?view=theater)). So, the moon travels *C<sub>m</sub>* X *R<sub>m</sub>* = 12474720576000 yojanas in a yuga consisting of 4320000 human yrs (called divya yr in Āryabhaṭīya 3.12). This is also the circumference of the sky (*C<sub>k</sub>*) (nabhaṅparidhi) in yojanas. It's presupposed that all the grahas travel the same linear distance in a yuga. In other words, *C<sub>j</sub>* X *R<sub>j</sub>* = *C<sub>k</sub>* is constant, for any *j*. In the case of the sun, whose rotations in a yuga (*R<sub>s</sub>*) are 4320000 (as per [Āryabhaṭīya 1.3-4](https://archive.org/details/Aryabhatiya1976/Aryabhatiya%20v1%201976/page/n79/mode/2up?view=theater)), its circumference (*C<sub>s</sub>*) is *C<sub>k</sub>* / *R<sub>s</sub>* = 2887666.8 yojanas. Therefore, the distance of the Sun from the earth is *C<sub>s</sub>* / *2π* ≈ 459585.37 yojanas (with Āryabhaṭa's value of *π* = 62832/20000 , as per Āryabhaṭīya [2.10](https://archive.org/details/Aryabhatiya1976/Aryabhatiya%20v1%201976/page/n117/mode/2up?view=theater)).

In Goladīpikā, [Parameśvara](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-4425-0_9588) directly mentions above calculated distance b/w sun & earth -

> *The Sun is a fiery orb with a radius of 4410 yojanas. The radius of its orbit is equal to 459585 yojanas* ~ Goladīpikā ([2.48](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.99495/page/n111/mode/2up?view=theater))

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem in this analysis of the line
“जुग सहस्र जोजन पर भानू। लील्यो ताहि मधुर फल जानू॥ १८ ॥”
is the assumption of the value of one yojana.

Aryabhatta calculated the circumference of the earth to be 4967 yojanas, wherein his definition of 1 yojana was approximately what is 5 miles today. Hence the value he arrived at was 24835 miles which is remarkably close to the current measurement of 24901 miles.

Therefore if a yojana is assumed to be 8 miles to support the verse in Hanuman Chalisa, then we will have to effectively falsify Aryabhatta's calculation.

Furthermore the word  yuga (जुग) is a measure of time and expressed in years (12000 years) therefore if you are multiplying two values the result must be expressed as a product of the units too. Therefore Yug and Yojana multiplied will give a value of 96,000,000 mile years and not 96,000, 000 miles. Thanks to Rishabh's blog for explaining it in detail (https://rishabh007blog.wordpress.com/2017/01/02/hanuman-chalisa-sun-earth-distance-calculation-hoax/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).